# `nohup` issue with submitting `SLURM` job

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

I have a python code `main.py` that runs bash script, the bash script inturn submits a job `job.bash` and obtains its `JOBID` using `echo $JOBID | awk {'print $4'}`. If I run python in the terminal, the bash script works and I am able to obtain and echo the `JOBID` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash 
JOBID=`sbatch ~/job.bash  | tee  output.log`
JOBID=`echo $JOBID | awk {'print $4'}`
echo $JOBID
```

Running above as part of python works in terminal `python main.py`, but doing `nohup python main.py &`, the echo does not print or store `JOBID`.

Any reason for this?

---

I am submitting a slurm job hence the `JOBID` is the pid from slurm

---

(Update Jul 17) Looks like the issue is with the command `sbatch ~/job.bash  | tee  output.log`, it doesnt get submitted using `nohup` and hence `JOBID` never gets stored and echo'd.

(Update Jul 18) As per the comments from @pynexj adding `set -x` in the script results:

```
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
+ date
Mon Jul 18 21:46:35 +03 2022
++ sbatch ~/job.bash
++ tee output.log
+ JOBID=
++ echo
++ awk '{print $4}'
+ JOBID=
+ echo
```

The issue still persists. It appears that `nohup` is incompatible with `sbatch`.

---

Question: Why should nohup prevent submission of slurm job? Its objective is merely to capture terminate signal?

Comment: " If the standard output is a terminal, the standard output is appended to the file nohup.out in the current
     directory."

Comment: @chepner but when i open `nohup.out`, nothing is echo'd there. The part with `JOBID` is blank

Comment: add `set -x` in the beginning and see what's happening.

Comment: Do you get the expected output in output.log? If not, the problem has nothing to do with `echo`, and probably is due to something about how `sbatch` works.

Comment: Also asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/710211/4667

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes you are right! it appears to be incompatibility between `sbatch` and `nohup`. I have updated my question.

Comment: @pynexj I have updated the question and implemented `set -x` the code merely gets printed in the terminal

Comment: It gets printed in the terminal _in a way that lets us see what's happening_; that's the whole point of using `set -x`.

Comment: For example, `JOBID=` in those logs tells us that `sbatch` isn't writing anything to stdout, so there's no jobid available to be stored. And `awk '{print $4}'` tells us that the weird way you're doing the quoting in your original code (putting the quotes inside the curly braces instead of the other way around) doesn't actually do any damage.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for clarification! I removed `sbatch` and added normal execution `~/./job.bash  | tee  output.log` and now I can see the echo values using `set -x`. Culprit is indeed `sbatch` running using `nohup` which still doesnt makes sense as to why it wont run `sbatch`

Comment: The main thing `nohup` does is redirect stdout and stderr when they aren't already going to files (it also closes stdin). Programs do sometimes check if those are going to a TTY or a file to decide on how they're going to behave based on that routing.

Comment: ...if that's the case, you'll see the same problem with `yourscript </dev/null >file.log 2>&1` even with nohup gone. If that _doesn't_ reproduce the problem we may have a piece of software that checks its parent to see if it's `nohup` -- which would be very weird -- but if you _do_ see that, you can just use `yourscript </dev/null >file.log 2>&1 & disown -h "$!"` to do literally everything nohup does without actually using nohup.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy AWSOME!! this works!! I have been biting my nails for a while over this and now its working. Please put this as an answer so i can accept! Also any speculation of why your solution works and nohup fails?

Comment: I suspect that sbatch is doing something nasty like looking at the process tree to see what its caller is, but would want to actually inspect its operation before I asserted something like that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this problem only happens with `nohup` present, you can get the benefits of `nohup` without actually using it with:

```
yourscript </dev/null >file.log 2>&1 & disown -h "$!"
```

This does the following:

- Redirects stdin from `/dev/null` with `</dev/null`
- Redirects stdout and stderr to a log file with `>file.log 2>&1`
- Tells the shell not to forward HUP signals to the background process with `disown -h "$!"`

...which is everything `nohup` does.

Comment: care to also comment on what this part `2>&1 & disown -h "$!"` does.

Comment: `2>&1` makes stderr go to the same place stdout does (thus, `file.log`). `&` puts the preceding in the background and stores its PID in `$!`. `disown -h "$!"` then tells the shell to stop tracking that background task in the job table, and also not to forward HUP signals on to it (this "not forwarding HUP signals" part is where the name "nohup" comes from).

Comment: makes so much sense! Thanks.